# TouchableOpacity not working inside an absolute positioned View

Tags: android, react-native

I have an absolute-positioned View that holds three TouchableOpacity components, and the three fail to respond they are just not working at all. What is going wrong here?

**Code**

```
<View style={[styles.highNormalLowDocListHeaderStateContainer, {width: this.windowWidth, height: this.headerSmallHeight, position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: floatedHeaderTitleTop, elevation: 2}]}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.getDocuments('high')} style={[styles.highNormalLowDocListHeaderStateTextContainer, highSelected.borderStyle]}>
        <Text style={[styles.highNormalLowDocListHeaderStateText, highSelected.textStyle]}>HIGH</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.getDocuments('normal')} style={[styles.highNormalLowDocListHeaderStateTextContainer, normalSelected.borderStyle]}>
        <Text style={[styles.highNormalLowDocListHeaderStateText, normalSelected.textStyle]}>NORMAL</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.getDocuments('low')} style={[styles.highNormalLowDocListHeaderStateTextContainer, lowSelected.borderStyle]}>
        <Text style {[styles.highNormalLowDocListHeaderStateText, lowSelected.textStyle]}>LOW</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Importing TouchableOpacity from "react-native-gesture-handler" worked for me

```
import { TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

Comment: For me, this fixed the touch event problem but introduced many other style/alignment issues. That being said, I think the style bugs are easier to resolve than the touchable one

Comment: Try using TouchableOpacity from react-native with debug and inspector disabled, or you can use the new api  [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable)

Comment: Interesting but my code worked when I import from react-native

Answer (score 89):

Just add `zIndex : 1` to the view containing the buttons.

Also note: adding elevation adds shadow to android button and sometimes elevation may also be a issue if it's added to parent and not added to child then the child button may not work (Rare Case).

eg:

```
buttonContainers:
  {
    zIndex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    position: 'absolute',
    top:5,
    right: 5,
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
    width: 80
  },
```

Comment: I am having an issue with elevation. I have something like `<View style={{top:70}}><TouchableOpacity/></View` , essentially 3 touchable components inside a <View> and if I add `top:70` only the shadow of the touchable component is clickable. What should I do? Adding `zIndex:1` didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Bn.F76 I actually have the same issue. zIndex:1 did not fix my issue either, did you find a solution?

Comment: some times really small things mess up the whole team Thanks Buddy

Comment: This should have been the answer.  Importing new libraries shouldn't be the priority instead of fixing the issue.

Comment: Worked great for <TouchableOpacity> in a <View> that is absolute position for me.

Comment: on Android it maybe elevation: 1

Answer (score 86):

Look at your import. If `import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';` doesn't work, you need import this from `'react-native'`.

Comment: The whole point of using `react-native-gesture-handle` is that they perform better so you'd be losing that.

Comment: They "perform better"? They don't work at all! I couldn't get the `onPress` handler of a `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native-gesture-handler` to do so much as an `alert` or a `console.log`. I imported it from `react-native` instead, and it just works.

Comment: Why on universe someone would import TouchableOpacity from react-native-gesture-handler ?

Comment: @RishavKumar have you heard of auto import?

Comment: @ThiagoLeite Not yet, did manual import may be that is why never imported from gesture handler

Comment: @RishavKumar I have some visual studio extensions that should help but sometimes get in the way. This is a case. He ends up importing from a wrong lib and we don't realize it.

Comment: this should be one of the worst auto-imports ever

Comment: another victim of auto-import! btw thanks, a true saviour!

Comment: Felt for this AGAIN today. The symptom is "why is my TouchableOpacity not styling properly?"

Comment: RNGH TouchableOpacity is just their improved version of the RN component - they do this with a few RN components and there is a difference, especially with smoothness of interactions and animations. The styling problems are because the RNGH version has a `containerStyle` prop for styling the outer view: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/1163#issuecomment-773626608

Answer (score 17):

Even though the tab bar visually appears to be above the content in the list, the touch events for the list may be receiving it before the tab bar. Add a zIndex to the tab bar to allow it to receive touch events first.

Answer (score 7):

If onPress of TouchableOpacity is not working,
In that case, TouchableNativeFeedback will work

Example:

```
{ Platform.OS === 'ios' ?
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.showPassordText()}>
    <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>SHOW</Text>  
  </TouchableOpacity>
  :
  <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => this.showPassordText()}>
    <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>SHOW</Text>
  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
}
```

Comment: TouchableNativeFeedback onPress doesn't work for Android if it has position: 'absolute'.

Comment: TouchableNativeFeedback worked for me on Android with position absolute.

Comment: Does not work for my on android with position absolute

Answer (score 5):

Often when do absolute positioning you have to put a zIndex because the absolute positioned ui view is sometimes being rendered behind another view

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by adding in a flex: 1 to each parent, and a height/ width to each. also try  pulling out each TouchableOpacity into separate view with flex:1 and adding absolute positioning to the child (text) element. I had an animation on my button so it may be a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the touchable items were inside a `FlatList`. Using `FlatList` from `'react-native-gesture-handler'` solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me are:

- Making sure I use

  ```
  import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
  ```
- Removing `flex: 1` and just having this style for my parent container:

  ```
  { width: '100%', height: '100%'}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Your absolute element is probably placed in a relative element. If you want to click it, you should remove parent relative rule.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the other answers but could not get it to work. In my case I had a parent container that had the following styles:

```
.parentContainer {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '-20%'
}
```

I realized that the children were overflowing out of the parent container and although it was not a big problem in terms of style, all the TouchableOpacity components that overflowed out of the parent container did not work (onPress event did not fire). Basically any TouchableOpacity component that ended up in the bottom 20% of the screen did not work because the parent had been moved up 20% (top: '-20%'). All I had to do was was change the height from `100%` to `120%` for the parent container and it started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

by importing **TouchableOpacity** from **"react-native-gesture-handler"** worked for me instead of giving the container View **z-index**

```
import { TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Add one more View or Div over Touchable opacity and give absolute positioning here

```html
<View style={{position: 'absolute'}}>
  <TouchableOpacity></TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
```

because when you make the View 'absolute' inside the TouchableOpacity element TouchableOpacity doesnt move with elements inside

```html
 <TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute'}}></View>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

> If you do like this above Touchable opacity doesnt move together with absolute element

Answer (score 0):

None of this answers here worked for me. I had to use
`import { TapGestureHandler } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';`
and wrap the children elements with `<TapGestureHandler onBegan={yourFunc} ></TapGestureHandler >`

The benefit of this is that it doesn't affect your styles and also accomplishes the same click effect you want. Generally I prefer this.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was simple but I don't understand why?

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('PRESSED')}>
   <View style={styles.fab}>
     <View style={styles.cartContainer}>
       <Text>{this.state.cartCount}</Text>
     </View>
     <Image source={CART} resizeMode="contain" />
   </View>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

To

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.fab} onPress={() => console.log('PRESSED')}>
  <View style={styles.cartContainer}>
    <Text>{this.state.cartCount}</Text>
  </View>
  <Image source={CART} resizeMode="contain" />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Styles

```
fab: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 40,
    right: 20,
    height: 60,
    width: 60,
}
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `TouchableHighlight` instead:

```
import {  TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";
```

and change the press color with `underlayColor={'lightgray'}`

Answer (score 0):

Adding z-index: 50 to the parent component will fix the problem.

Comment: adding `z-index` was already mentioned in a previous answer.

Comment: You need to add the z-index to the parent element, not the element itself.

Comment: then maybe improve the answer and include an example?