# TouchableOpacity inside header is affected by view with absolute position in the screen on android

Tags: react-native

I have a `View`inside a `SafeAreaView` in a screen which has `postion:absolute`. When I include the view, a `TouchableOpacity` rendered in the header no longer responds in ANDROID (but always works fine in iOS).

Home screen:

```
render() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.SafeAreaContainer}>
      <View style={styles.homeBackgroundContainer}>  {/* <--- offending view! */}
        <BlueCircle style={styles.homeBackgroundSvg} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.homeView}>
        <View style={styles.homeGreetingContainer}>
          <Title style={styles.homeGreeting}>Hi, </Title>
          <Title style={styles.homeGreetingName}>{username}</Title>
        </View>
        // Other components
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

styles.homeBackgroundContainer:

```
homeBackgroundContainer: {
  borderColor: COLOR.transparent,
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '-50%',
  left: '-25%',
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
},
```

The header is declared in the drawer navigator screen options. Note the TouchableOpacity in the header - this is used to open the drawer.

- works in iOS
- works from the "Content" screen
- works when the `homeBackgroundContainer`(and its children) are commented out (Home Screen)
- DOES NOT WORK IN ANDROID when `homeBackgroundContainer` is rendered (Home Screen).

Drawer Navigation & Header:

```
function DrawerContainer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={({navigation}) => ({
        headerLeft: titleLogo,
        headerStyle: {
          // colors only
        },
        headerTitle: () => {},
        headerRight: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.hamburgerIconButton}
            onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/hamburger.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      })}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          // more options
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Content"
        component={ContentScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

styles.hamburgerIconButton:

```
hamburgerIconButton: {
  marginRight: 20,
},
```

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36938742/4109824) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39250449/4109824) on SO have shown that absolute positioning can affect TouchableOpacity. I have tried setting the zIndex of the TouchableOpacity to 1, and also tried setting a positive elevation value but there is no change in behaviour.

Visually, I can see the header colors and content is rendered on top of the view which is the desired state. So if the header is rendered over the view, why isn't the TouchableOpacity responding?

Comment: Just add `zIndex: -1` to `homeBackgroundContainer`

Comment: Have just tried this now, there's no change in behviour.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `TouchableOpacity`in a navigation header to respond on android when there's a view on the screen which has `postion: absolute`, I had to bring the `headerStyle`(not the touchable opacity style) forward on the z-axis.

```
screenOptions={() => ({
  headerStyle: {
    zIndex: 1,
  },
})};
```

Comment: This worked after metro refreshed the app, but after a new build it stopped working again.