# How to use zIndex in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox

I've want to achieve the following:

[image]

The following images are what I can do right now, but that's NOT what I want.
[image: scenarioA][image: scenarioB]

Sample of code I have right now:

```
renderA() {
    return (
        <View style={ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 0 }>    // parent of A
            <View style={ zIndex: 2 }>  // element A
            </View>
            <View style={ zIndex: 2 }>  // element A
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

renderB() {
    return (
        <View style={ position: 'absolute', zIndex: 1 }>    // element B
        </View>
    );
}


render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this.renderA()}
            {this.renderB()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

To put it in words, I want

- **Parent A:** to be below everything.
- **Element B:** to be at the above parent A but below element A.
- **Element A:** above everything.

Note that **Parent A** and **Element B** both have to be **absolutely** positioned, and both elements A and elements B have to be **clickable**...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally solved this by creating a second object that imitates B.

My schema now looks like this:

[image]

I now have B1 (within parent of A) and B2 outside of it.

B1 and B2 are right next to one another, so to the naked eye it looks as if it's just 1 object.

Comment: That seems more like a kluge than a reproducible solution. Anyone have a more engineered solution?

Comment: I thought you said you don't want B to be inside parent of A. How is this better than the most upvoted answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943191/how-to-use-zindex-in-react-native/42654930?noredirect=1#comment99367539_41943372

Answer (score 95):

Use `elevation` instead of `zIndex` for android devices

```js
elevatedElement: {
  zIndex: 3, // works on ios
  elevation: 3, // works on android
}
```

This worked fine for me!

Comment: You just ended a full day of debugging on Android. "elevation" on Android, not "zIndex". Argh! This seems like a deviation from standard CSS. "elevation" is supposed to affect drop shadows and such; aeshetic only, and not comparable with z-index.

Comment: For me, the elevation only fixes the problem visually, i.e. the previously hidden elements are now visible, but at this state they are not interactive any more (i.e. buttons etc cannot be clicked). The only solution (for Android at least) seems to be the appropriate ordering of elements.

Answer (score 54):

I believe there are different ways to do this based on what you need exactly, but one way would be to just put both Elements A and B inside Parent A.

```js
<View style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>    // parent of A
  <View style={{ zIndex: 1 }} />  // element A
  <View style={{ zIndex: 1 }} />  // element A
  <View style={{ zIndex: 0, position: 'absolute' }} />  // element B
</View>
```

Comment: I thought of that, but I have to keep the structure as is..! 
There's a good reason why I don't want to add elements B in the parent of A view.
I simplified my question, but there are lots of **parent of A** Views containing lots of element A's.
I appreciate the answer though, thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it the way you want it. The parent's Z-index will be evaluated first, then the children will be compared to other children. Here is a similar post the goes into more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490146/z-index-relative-or-absolute

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking something like keep the last image (3rd scenario)
but  i.e disregard touches on the *parent A*  (which will be transparent anyway) and let the event pass to *element B* even if it's below *parent A*. And of course if *element A* is rendered, it should always receive the touch handler.

Comment: Actually, that might work...set pointerEvents to 'box-none' on the parent A. This will make elements A clickable, and you will be able to click through the parent to reach element B behind it.

Comment: add least use proper syntax... style={{ }}

Comment: That doesn't work on Android, element B will get cropped because parent A is not wide enough.

Comment: Also, for anyone coming here because iOS doesn't seem to care about the zIndex, check that both elements are siblings, see the comment at the bottom of this page https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#zindex, "On iOS, zIndex may require Views to be siblings of each other for it to work as expected."

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Supposedly, `zIndex` has been added to the `react-native` library. I've been trying to get it to work without success. Check [here](https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/zindex-support) for details of the fix.

Comment: It works as intended. After playing around with it a bit, I figured out how to use it correctly. Styling for mobile has always *appeared* deceptively simple but in truth is not.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve the desired solution with CSS z-index either, as z-index is only relative to the parent element. So if you have parents A and B with respective children a and b, b's z-index is only relative to other children of B and a's z-index is only relative to other children of A.

The z-index of A and B are relative to each other if they share the same parent element, but all of the children of one will share the same relative z-index at this level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Elevation property in your StyleSheet

```
containerText: {
    elevation: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#FB8500',
    padding: 3,
    borderRadius: 15,
    marginTop: -30,
    marginLeft: -10,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `zIndex` for **iOS** and `elevation` for **android** devices to stack the view on top of one another.

```
element: {
  zIndex: 1, // 1 for stacking the element on top of the previous element and -1 
             // for stacking the element under the above previous element.
  elevation: 1,
}
```