# React native Several modals opened priority

Tags: react-native

I have several modals in jsx

```
<View>
  <Modal id="first" visible>
    <View>
      <Text>123</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => this.setState({ secondVisible: true })}>Open Modal</Button>
    </View>
  </Modal>
  <Modal id="second" visible={this.state.secondVisible}>
    <View>
      <Text>123</Text>
    </View>
  </Modal>
</View>
```

I open #first than inside it i press button and do #second visible.
Is it possible to give some zIndex to #second so it can be always on top.
Modal in Modal i cant do because its sharable so can be opened from several places

Comment: Can we assign ID to elements in React native? I guess we can't? Literally asking

Comment: Also this question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943191/how-to-use-zindex-in-react-native

Comment: Id its just to give connections in description.  
Is it possible to give Modal zIndex ?